# Problema com o LocalStorage

Tags: javascript

ajuda aqui por favor. Nessa minha To Do List quando eu crio ou deleto itens eles continuam salvos ao dar refresh, e quando eu clico no checkbox ele aplica um CSS no LI tachando a palavra, só que quando eu dou refresh essa animação do CSS não fica salvo, como faço para salvar isso? Como a Li está dentro da variável TODOS achei que fosse salvar automaticamente, mas não é o que está acontecendo.

Agradeço desde já.

```
var geraUl = document.querySelector('.caixa ul'); 
var pegaInput = document.querySelector('.campos #input'); 
var botao = document.querySelector('#botao');



var todos = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('to_do_list'))  || [] ;  


function mostrarTodos(){        

    geraUl.innerHTML ='';      

    for (item of todos) {       
        var newtodoli = document.createElement('li');     
        var label = document.createElement('label');
        var newtodotext = document.createTextNode(item);  
        var checkbox = document.createElement('input');   
        var img = document.createElement('img')



        checkbox.setAttribute('type', 'checkbox');
        checkbox.setAttribute('class', 'check');
        checkbox.setAttribute('id', 'checkbox');
        checkbox.addEventListener('click', tacharLi);

        img.setAttribute('src', './files/lixeira.svg');


        label.setAttribute('for', 'checkbox');




        var pos = todos.indexOf(item);   


        img.setAttribute('onclick', 'deletarLi(' + pos + ')');  






        geraUl.appendChild(newtodoli); 
        newtodoli.appendChild(newtodotext);         
        newtodoli.appendChild(checkbox);    
        newtodoli.appendChild(img)  ;





    }

}

mostrarTodos();




function Addtodo(){                          
    var txtadd = pegaInput.value ;           
    if (txtadd.length == 0 ) {             
        alert("Digite alguma tarefa.")
    } else {

    todos.push(txtadd);                
    pegaInput.value = '';               
    mostrarTodos();
    saveToStorage();

}}


function deletarLi(pos){                    

    todos.splice(pos, 1);               
    mostrarTodos();
    saveToStorage();
}


function tacharLi(){

        this.parentNode.classList.toggle('tachar')


    saveToStorage();

}




botao.onclick = Addtodo;              



document.addEventListener('keypress', function(e){     
    if(e.which == 13){

        Addtodo();

    }
 }, false);

function saveToStorage () {                

    localStorage.setItem('to_do_list', JSON.stringify(todos));


}
```

caso precise ver os outros arquivos o link do github é https://github.com/ricardogusi/to-do-list

Answer (score 0):

Bom vamos por pontos.

Você esta usando a mesma função para salvar e deletar item na localStore, seria melhor ter duas funções uma para salvar e outra para deletar.

Podendo usar

```
localStorage.removeItem(key);
```

E no caso do css, para preservar o estilo pode criar uma flag no item inserido, tipo checked que em primeiro momento seira 0 e caso o user clicasse no item faria o update para 1 e ai sim a classe seria aplicada.

Espero ter ajudado.